# What is the link snapshort called and can I control what is shown in that?

Tags: html

In whatsapp & fb messenger, when you share a link. A snapshort like (https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGSTZ.jpg) appears. What is that called and can I control what my url should display?

I was unable to get anything from Google so I figured that I am not using the right keyword.

Comment: A preview window, perhaps?  It's not a standardized control.

Comment: I thought it was part of html5. It seems to part of OpenGraph. "og:" in <meta/>.

Comment: I wasn't getting any result with the keywords I was using in Google, thats why I posted this. I don't want to edit or delete the question, hoping it will help the next clueless person. I personally went around asking this question to many people and everyone was clueless.

Comment: https://blog.vwriter.com/ultimate-guide-to-social-meta-tags-open-graph-and-twitter-cards/